# nodejs session timeout doesn't work for the specified time

Tags: node.js, express

I have a `nodejs` web app, I have set session timeout to 2 hours but the session is getting timed out before 2 hours,
My nodejs app is deployed in google cloud app engine.
This is how I have setup the session

```
app.use(session({
   resave: true , 
   rolling: true,
   secret: '****' , 
   genid: function(req) { return uuid(); },
   saveUninitialized: true,
   cookie: {
    maxAge: 7200000 
}}));
```

I need my session to be active even if there is no hit on web for 2 hours. and if there are request on web, session need to be rollout.
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a timezone difference issue.

From the docs:

`cookie.maxAge`: Specifies the number (in milliseconds) to use when calculating the Expires Set-Cookie attribute. This is done by taking the current server time and adding maxAge milliseconds to the value to calculate an Expires datetime.

I would suggest you use
`cookie.expires` with UTC values:
Specifies the Date object to be the value for the Expires Set-Cookie attribute

Comment: Glad that I helped!